# Имитация звуковой карты

Tags: qt

Добрый день! Используем Qt.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно имитировать звуковую карту, чтобы использовать ее из других программ, т.е. перенаправлять звук куда надо?

Comment: Честно говоря, я не очень понял что требуется сделать. То есть вы написали программу Х. И теперь вы хотите перенаправить звук из программы Y в эту программу X, так?

Comment: в данном случае Qt не нужно. Для начала Вам нужно разобраться, для какой операционной оси это будет. Если для Windows, тогда читать как делать драйвера + ddk. Если Linux, тогда классика - [ldd](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/). А Qt  в данном случае разве что для gui утилиты-настройки.

Comment: Спасибо! Сделаю кроссплатформенную версию)